# PyQt5 VideoPlayer: Converting to Object Orientated Code Prevents Playback

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, pyqt5, opencv, python

I've been looking into how to incorporate a video or livestream into an app. I have found some functional code that works fine:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import cv2 # OpenCV
import qimage2ndarray # for a memory leak,see gist
import sys # for exiting

# Minimal implementation...

def displayFrame():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = qimage2ndarray.array2qimage(frame)
    label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))

app = QApplication([])
window = QWidget()

# OPENCV

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("Vid.mp4")
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240)

# timer for getting frames

timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(displayFrame)
timer.start(60)
label = QLabel('No Camera Feed')
button = QPushButton("Quiter")
button.clicked.connect(sys.exit) # quiter button
layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(button)
layout.addWidget(label)
window.setLayout(layout)
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

And I am trying to be able to use this in some object orientated code, with the aim of creating a video playback widget to incorporate into other apps:

```
import cv2
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import qimage2ndarray # for a memory leak,see gist
import sys # for exiting

# Minimal implementation...
class basicWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(basicWindow, self).__init__()

        # OPENCV

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture("Vid.mp4")
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240)

        # timer for getting frames

        timer = QTimer()
        timer.timeout.connect(displayFrame)
        timer.start(60)
        label = QLabel('No Camera Feed')
        button = QPushButton("Quiter")
        button.clicked.connect(sys.exit)  # quiter button
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(button)
        layout.addWidget(label)
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

def displayFrame():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image = qimage2ndarray.array2qimage(frame)
        try:
            label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    windowExample = basicWindow()
    windowExample.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm new to both OO coding and PyQt5, so any advice on how I'm either misinterpreting how the code works or what Im missing would be great. I have tried already setting label to a global variable, as I wasnt sure the function displayFrame() was aware of what label to change with `label.setPixmap`, but otherwise Im a little lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example it works because `label` is a *global* variable, so `displayFrame` can access it as such.
In the other case, `label` is only declared in the scope of the `__init__` of the `basicWindow` instance, so `displayFrame` knows nothing about it.

Make label a member of the instance (`self.label = QLabel()`), `displayFrame` a method of the basicWindow class (`def displayFrame(self):`) and then access the label correctly; note that you also need to make both `cap` and `timer` member of the instance (`self`), otherwise their objects will be immediately "garbage collected" after `__init__` returns.

```
class basicWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(basicWindow, self).__init__()
        # ...
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture("Vid.mp4")
        # ...
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.displayFrame)
        self.timer.start(60)
        self.label = QLabel('No Camera Feed')
        # ...

    def displayFrame(self):
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()
        if ret:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            image = qimage2ndarray.array2qimage(frame)
            try:
                self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

Since you're new to OO programming, I suggest you to start by studying how [classes and instances](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) and [name resolution](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names) work in python.

Comment: Ahh i did try making it a global variable, didnt consider making it a class variable. Ill try that now cheers. Edit: Still not working i'm afraid. Edit2: It isnt even running the self.displayFrame function, put a ```print("here")``` to check.

Comment: Global variables should be avoided unless absolutely necessary and only if you really know what you're doing (which, usually, means that you're probably doing something wrong, as you should know that you should never use them :-) ). In any case, global functions (those that are not members of a class) should only be used when they need to be accessed "globally". Since `displayFrame` is only important for the basicWindow class instance, it should be a member of that class anyway, and that's a very important aspect about OO programming.

Comment: @Jkind9 Sorry, my bad. Make timer a member of the class (`self.timer = ...`) or set a parent for it (`timer = QTimer(self)`).

Comment: Tried both of those and for some reason the program is crashing. Still not able to see the print statements before the crash eitehr

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to test it, as I cannot use cv2 right now. I just found out that also `cap` is local; make it a member of the instance too, then if still doesn't work, try running the code from a shell/command prompt to see the full traceback.